# Error while installing Socket.io by npm

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I got the below message while installing Socket.io in Node.js

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

> ```
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: node-v0.10.35.tar.gz local checksum efd2c6bfd05834bca81175fa1b6374898c95c9e2a57597e6ac3a8594d37bc4a0 not match remote 0043656bb1724cb09dbdc960a2fd6ee37d3badb2f9c75562b2d11235daa40a03
> gyp ERR! stack     at deref (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:299:20)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:409:24)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
> gyp ERR! stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1096:12)
> gyp ERR! stack     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
> gyp ERR! stack     at _stream_readable.js:944:16
> gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\ruchi data\My Programs\meanstack\socket\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
> gyp ERR! not ok
> ```

Comment: I was able to install it. Which OS are u using?

Comment: checksum doesn't match. Seems like network corruption. Try installing again, and/or clearing your [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache)

Answer (score 0):

I have windows 10 x64. I have installed python 2.7.3 and added to my path as mentioned in nodegyp . I have installed visual studio 2013 community. and also have installed [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). still i was getting the error while installing socket.io or other native modules like bcrypt.

Then I tried to install socket.io by the following command

```
npm install --save socket.io --msvs_version=2013
```

This solved the problem and installed socket.io without any error. The trick is

```
npm install <package name> --msvs_version=2013
```